# Query: getting the last record for each member trouble cause by another value

Tags: mysql

i have data below for example

```
     id      product_id   date  
  ------     ----------   ----
     1           1         1
     2           1         2
     3           1         3
     4           2         1
     5           2         2
     6           2         2
     7           3         1
```

result data query that i want "the last record of last date on each product_id"

to get it that result i use the query like below

```
SELECT a.* FROM test AS a 
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id, product_id, MAX(DATE) AS DATE FROM test GROUP BY product_id) AS b 
  ON a.id = b.id AND a.product_id = b.product_id AND a.date = b.date
```

this time i got what i want as the result

```
    id  product_id    date  
------  ----------  --------
     3           1         3
     6           2         2
     7           3         1
```

my problem when i add another data like below

```
    id  product_id    date  
------  ----------  --------
     1           1         1
     2           1         2
     3           1         3
     4           2         1
     5           2         2
     6           2         2
     7           3         1
     8           1         3
     9           1         2
```

and use the same query the result become like this

```
    id  product_id    date  
------  ----------  --------
     6           2         2
     7           3         1
```

where the the value '1' for product_id?

Comment: You mean id = 9, product_id = 1, date = 2 ?

Comment: no, id=8 cause the last date is 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT id, product_id, DATE FROM test sitem WHERE product_id IN (1,2,3) AND DATE = (SELECT DATE FROM test WHERE product_id = 
sitem.product_id ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 1) AND id = 
(SELECT id FROM test WHERE product_id = sitem.product_id ORDER BY DATE DESC, 
id DESC LIMIT 1) GROUP BY product_id
```

Comment: Your should remove this in your query 'product_id IN (1,2,3) AND'

Answer (score 0):

This is your subquery:

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS id, product_id, MAX(DATE) AS DATE
FROM test
GROUP BY product_id
```

It is independently calculating the maximum of `id` and `date`.  But, there is no guarantee that these two values are in the same record.  There are ways to fix the subquery, but they are rather complicated.

Instead, I would suggest using an alternative method to get the last record:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM test t2
                  WHERE t2.product_id = t.product_id AND
                        (t2.date > t.date OR
                         t2.date = t.date AND t2.id > t.id
                 );
```

This identifies the last record for each product as the one where no other record has a larger date.  And, if two records have the same date, no other record has a larger id.